# How to pass data using CloudKit's notification?

Tags: swift, notifications, cloudkit, subscription

I'm trying to pass one string in my notification through CloudKit's subscription. But, when I print this string in my iPhone, it's nil! Here is my code:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    print(userInfo)

    let cloudKitNotification = CKNotification(fromRemoteNotificationDictionary: userInfo as! [String : NSObject])
    print(cloudKitNotification)
    if cloudKitNotification.notificationType == CKNotificationType.Query {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("performReload", object: nil)
            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("performReloadItem", object: nil)

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            let destinationViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("EventoViewController") as! EventoViewController

            let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
            navigationController.pushViewController(destinationViewController, animated: false)
        })
    }
}
```

And here it is when I set the subscription:

```
let predicateItem = NSPredicate(format: "self contains '\(self.eventoID)'")

    let subscriptionItem = CKSubscription(recordType: "Itens",
                                      predicate: predicateItem,
                                      options: [.FiresOnRecordCreation, .FiresOnRecordUpdate])

    let notificationInfoItem = CKNotificationInfo()
    notificationInfoItem.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
    notificationInfoItem.desiredKeys = ["idEvento"]
    notificationInfoItem.shouldBadge = false
    subscriptionItem.notificationInfo = notificationInfo

    let publicdbItem = CKContainer.defaultContainer().publicCloudDatabase
    publicdbItem.saveSubscription(subscriptionItem) { (returnRecord, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            print("ITEM subscription ok!\n")
        }
    }
```

Shouldn't only *notificationInfoItem.desiredKeys = ["idEvento"]* be enough to pass me that data? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've set up the `CKNotificationInfo` right, you just need to access it like so in your `didRecieveRemoteNotificationHandler`:

```
if let queryNotification = notification as? CKQueryNotification{
    let id = query.recordFields?["idEvento"] as? String
}
```

Or whatever type `idEvento` happens to be. Keep in mind that the only supported types of properties for desired keys are strings, numbers, locations, dates and references.

Comment: Thanks so much for your comment! Did not know about that!! But just one question, how do I treat the _id_ variable now? I thought that all the _recordFields_ that I wanted would come in _userInfo_... I pass it to the destination VC like a normal segue? Once again, thanks for your attention

Comment: Yeah you can pass on the id variable now however you want, you can get the fields from the userInfo dictionary I think but it's generally easier to just convert it to a CKNoticication object. If idEvento isn't a string you can just cast it to any of the other types mentioned in the answer